# Ignore errors when running npm scripts sequentially

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, command-line, sh

Whenever I build my project to be served, I have to execute three scripts:

```
npm run build:local     //calls tsc to compile ts into js files
npm run build:webpack   //invokes webpack to bundle js files into one minified file 
npm run serve           //runs my lite-server to preview files
```

I wanted to run these commands sequentially as:

```
npm run build:local && npm run build:webpack && npm run serve
```

However, due to needing to have some JQuery in my ts files, I get an error during `npm run build:local` that throws `Cannot find name '$'.` However, my code compiles it anyways, and that line is critical to my project, so it needs to be there (for now).  That error stops the sequential execution of the script.  Is there a way to ignore errors and keep executing down the chain?

Comment: This is a question concerning the shell you're running this in rather than about npm. What shell _are_ you using?

Comment: @Timo Sorry!  I'm running in bash

Comment: @TimoStaudinger Actually, I feel this *should* be a question on how to do this with NPM only, meaning cross-platform. Too many NPM scripts use shell specific features for things that can be done cross-platform with the right approach. Note that the accepted answer suggests `npm-run-all`, which is indeed cross-platform.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
npm run build:local ; npm run build:webpack && npm run serve
```

I think of `&&` as meaning "only run this next command if the last one doesn't error." And `;` as meaning "run this next command no matter what happens to the last one." There is also `||`, which means "run the next command only if the last one errors." That's handy for things like `npm run build:local || echo "The build failed!"`

You can also do the following if you install [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/HEAD/docs/npm-run-all.md)

```
npm-run-all -s -c build:local build:webpack serve
```

- `-s` run as sequence
- `-c` continue on error

Comment: it didn't work me  , this is what I have in scripts of package.json
{
"sample:test": "npm run lint:app:some-viewer;npm run lint:app:some-viewer-e2e"}

error:  missing script: lint:app:some-viewer;npm

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to this issue. Please post a new question and describe your OS and environment.

Answer (score 5):

You can go for

```
npm run build:local; npm run build:webpack; npm run serve
```

You can read more why that works [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/539293)

Comment: it didn't work me 
package.json```
"sample:test": "npm run lint:app:some-viewer;npm run lint:app:some-viewer-e2e",
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this in bash:

```
(npm run build:local || true) && (npm run build:webpack || true) && (npm run serve || true)
```

You could then alias this as a separate script in your package.json:

```
bar: (npm run build:local || true) && (npm run build:webpack || true) && (npm run serve || true)
```

("bar" = "build and run")

And run as:

```
npm run bar
```