# How to run test file after launching server using npm scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, npm-scripts

I wanted to exploit the `npm script` capacities and I tried to create a command to run the tests of my API. Basically I need to launch the API and perform some HTTP requests. I have the tests in a JS file, let's call it `automatic-test.js`, and I wanted to launch the API and then run these tests.

In my `package.json`, I tried this call:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "npm start & node test/automatic-test.js"
}
```

The `test` command starts the API server but it doesn't run the tests file. I tried changing `&` by `&&`, `||` and `;` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419424/ignore-errors-when-running-npm-scripts-sequentially)), but none of it makes the command line to reach the second part of the command. I tried to even write the content of the `start` command at the beginning of the `test` one, but the problem is the same.

I could find a workaround launching the server from the test file ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929621/how-to-start-two-commands-sequentially-in-node-js-application)), `require('/route/to/server/file')`, leaving the `test` command just like `node test/automatic-test.js` but I feel like maybe I'm cheating with that. What should I do to make this statement work as I want to?

```
npm start &/&&/||/; node test/automatic-test.js
```

Node version: v10.15.0

Npm version: 6.4.1

EDIT: these tests are a very first draft of the future real tests, and are just a bunch of HTTP requests which should only return a very small set of results, they are not proper tests (assessments, mocha, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default node doesn't provide ability to test directly you have to add package like [mocha](https://mochajs.org/)

Please follow the docs.

Comment: I've just added an edit explaining further about these tests I'm trying. Thanks in advance.

Comment: npm install --save-dev start-server-and-test use this module then you can run test after server start

Comment: You can check this for reference https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Boot-your-server

Answer (score 1):

The [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) npm package is pretty sweet, imho.

It claims to be *"Like npm run watch-js & npm run watch-less but better"* and since your question started with `&` tying the commands...

Here's an example from a `package.json`:

```
    "test:dev": "concurrently --restart-tries 10 --names rollup,sirv \"rollup --config rollup.test.config.js -w\" \"sirv test --port 3000 --single --dev\"",
```

It prints the names ("rollup", "sirv") to the output so it become clear, which process did what.

I'm unable to compare with `start-server-and-test` which was already mentioned.